# ASP.Net MVC - Jquery Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Net MVC controller with this SQL query to return a value, in which I have a field that has Email.
The email is being passed and read by the query but the value isn't being transfered over the View with Json.

This is my controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult hhhhhh(string email)
{

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Example;Initial Catalog=Example;User ID=example;Password=example;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT anr.Name FROM AspNetUsers anu  " +
                                     "LEFT JOIN AspNetUserRoles anur ON (anur.UserId = anu.Id) " +
                                     "LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles anr ON (anr.Id = anur.RoleId) " +
                                     "WHERE anu.Email = '" + email + "'", cn);


    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    return Json(cmd, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

This is my View:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      var str = '@User.Identity.GetUserName()'; //returns the current email
      $.getJSON("/Student/hhhhhh", {
        email: str
      }, function(data) {
        alert(data.cmd)
        if (data == "Admin") {
          alert("asddsadas");
        } else {
          alert("n deu");
        }
        /* if (data = "Admin") {
        alert("DEUEUEUEUEU");
        }
        else {
        alert("ndeu");
        }*/

      });

</script>
```

This is returning me an undefined value.
Can you guys identify the error ?

Comment: You're using `ExecuteNonQuery()` with a `SELECT` statement, which is incorrect. Try `ExecuteReader()` instead and return the result of that in whatever format you require, not the Command. See the 'Query data' section here: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson03

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$getjson(
// Send data from here
).done(
 // On success whatever you want to do
).fail(
// On fail whatever you want to do
)
```

Your request might be getting failed. Using getjson this way you can exactly check where request is going is failing or getting success than we can debug further.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is supposed to be used for queries that does not return any data like update, insert, delete... If you want to execute a select query you have to use `ExecuteReader` and get your results as a `DataReader` object, Also you can't pass directly an SqlCommand Object to JsonResult You need a Dictionary Or a List of objects, try this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult hhhhhh(string email)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=Example;Initial Catalog=Example;User ID=example;Password=example;";

    // note the 'using' statement
    using( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) ) {

        string query = "SELECT anr.Name FROM AspNetUsers anu  " +
                        "LEFT JOIN AspNetUserRoles anur ON (anur.UserId = anu.Id) " +
                        "LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles anr ON (anr.Id = anur.RoleId) " +
                        "WHERE anu.Email = @email";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        // note how to pass parameter to SqlCommand object
        command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        command.Parameters["@email"].Value = email;

        connection.Open();

        // We can use a Dictionary for example to produce json result 
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        using( SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {

            while (reader.Read()) {

                for (i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                    dict.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                }

            }

        }

        return Json(dict, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```